# Side effects within xsl:accumulator

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

It appears that `xsl:message` does not work (i.e. no output is generated to message list) within an `accumulator-rule`. However, I don't see anything in the spec that disallows this.

```xml
<xsl:accumulator name="acc1" streamable="yes" initial-value="1">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="cdf:ContestSelection">
          <xsl:message>Output</xsl:message>
        </xsl:accumulator-rule>
<xsl:accumulator>
```

Comment: Is the accumulator used by the mode and is the rule matching? I tested a simple example with Saxon 10 and as long as the accumulator is used by the mode and the rule matches I get an output from the `xsl:message`.

Comment: I only tested with Saxon from the command line, if "no output is generated to message list" means you are using Saxon's API it might help if you show the code for that or at least explain which version and which API you use.

Answer (score 0):

There's all sort of possible reasons for this: the accumulator is never used, the rule never fires, the optimizer optimizes the call on `xsl:message` away, etc. One would need a complete repro to see what is actually going on.

Note that pretty well everything about `xsl:message` is implementation-defined, and one reason for that is to give the processor maximum freedom for optimization.

Comment: I know the accumulator rule is used, as I can verify the values being set. I'll post a more complete example.

Comment: What may be happening is that the `xsl:message` is evaluated, but not at the time you expect it.